# How commit and rollback exactly works in databases?

Tags: java, database, postgresql, jdbc, transactions

Imagine two threads accessing a DB that maintains user's balances, which is initially 10 units.

Thread 1: withdraw 5 units of currency

```
1.a read balance from DB
1.b decrement balance in memory
1.c write decremented balance in DB
```

Thread 2: deposit 3 units of currency

```
2.a read balance from DB 
2.b increment balance in memory
2.c write incremented balance in DB
```

If the steps are interleaved, and we start with a balance of 10, then we can end up with the lost update problem as follows:

```
Real world seq of events:

1.a read balance from DB (10)
1.b decrement balance in memory (10 - 5 = 5)
2.a read balance from DB (10)
1.c write decremented balance in DB (5)
2.b increment balance in memory (10 + 3 = 13)
2.c write incremented balance in DB (13)
```

Here we lose the update of 1.c. How does `setAutoCommit(false)` and `commit` solve the problem? Suppose the code is:

```
setAutoCommit(false)
1.a read balance from DB
1.b decrement balance in memory
1.c write decremented balance in DB
commit(), and if error, rollback()
```

Will commit throw if the database has been changed before 1.c? I cannot find any examples that explain how commit/rollback works in error cases.

Comment: Technically this is not Java or JDBC related, but purely with how transactions in databases work.

Comment: I am interested in how this behaves in case of JDBC and PostgreSQL

Comment: It would behave the same if you didn't use JDBC (but did it directly in PostgreSQL, or used a different language/driver), asking your question without considering JDBC will make it broader.

Comment: Changed title to make it generic.

Comment: You are confusing two different concepts. 1) Commit/Rollback, 2) Isolation level. To control the sequence of charges, you'll need to raise the isolation level. Transactions don't really care about that; they only ensure ALL/NONE operations are executed.

Answer (score 2):

There are three possibilities to avoid a lost update like this:

1. **Pessimistic locking:**

   Use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` to read the balance from the database.

   That will take a row lock upon read. The concurrent transaction that wants to work on the same row will be locked until the first transaction commits. You have to use an explicit transaction; in JDBC you would disable autocommit.

   This is a good strategy for short transactions, if a longer lock on the row is no problem.
2. **Optimistic locking using transaction isolation:**

   Use transaction isolation level `REPEATABLE READ` for all transactions that want to perform an update like that.

   Then the second transaction will get a *serialization error* when it updates. That is not an error that should be propagated to the user, it is rather a sign that the transaction should be retried.

   This is a good method for short transactions if you want to hold locks as short as possible and are willing to retry transactions that receive a serialization error. You have to use an explicit transaction; in JDBC you would disable autocommit.
3. **Optimistic locking using the application:**

   You update like this:

   ```
   UPDATE account SET balance = <new value>
   WHERE id = ... AND balance = <value you originally read>;
   ```

   Then you check if the update has modified a row or not (“update count”). If not, the balance has been changed in the meantime and you should retry the action.

   **Note:** This only checks if `balance` has been modified since we read the row. If you want the update to fail if *anything* has changed about the row, you'll have extend the `WHERE` condition.

   This is the best method if the time between reading the balance and the update are not short, e.g. if there is a user interaction inbetween. It does not require the use of database transactions.

Comment: In the case #3 you need to check account version not the value of the balance. Otherwise you have issue in the following example. Tx means transaction with id x, B means balance. Initially: B=10; T1: get B; T1: B=B+3; T2: read B; T2: B=B-3; T1: get B, B is still 10, so B=B+3. The end result is B=13 but should be 10.

Comment: The point is that you check and update at the same time, so that cannot happen. One of the two "transactions" must update first, and the other one cannot but see the changed value.

Comment: Option #1 works (in databases that support it). Option #2 *does not work*, sorry. For option #3 to work you'll need to add an extra column for version control, that is incremented and checked on each update (checking the balance is not 100% bulletproof).

Comment: @TheImpaler Option 2 works in PostgreSQL. Prove otherwise if you can. With option 3, we ignore other changes to the row and only avoid losing updates to `balance`. I'll add a comment to my answer to make that clear.

Comment: @TheImpaler - The statement *does not work* is really insufficient. In Postgres phantom read is not allowed in repeatable read isolation level, so #2 works well. Solution #3 refers only to modifications of the `balance` column. If the value of the column is as expected, the update will be correct.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe: I'm sorry I didn't realize this was a PostgreSQL question (my fault). I have tested strategy #2 numerous times in several rdbms, and it doesn't work, even when raising the isolation level. The only options are **pessimistic locking** (your option #1) or **optimistic locking** (your option #3 -- that I would improve). Option #2 is -- in general -- not safe for most databases.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe: I see now why I was confused with the option #3. From the description I understand it that there are three steps: 1. read value 2. update conditionally with new value 3. reread again to check if value is updated.  Now I understand that there is no step 3 and the check if update was done should be based on modified rows number of the update on step 2.

Comment: @RomanKonoval you are right, there's no step three. Just look at the number of modified rows and there you have it. But again, please note this is not the standard implementation of optimistic locking, that requires an extra "version control" column.

Comment: I don't think that there is a standard for optimistic locking. The term just refers to the fact that you don't forbid concurrent activity, but hope that everything will go well and risk retrying if it doesn't.

Comment: @RomanKonoval You are right, it was a bit unclear. I have tried to improve the wording.

Comment: @TheImpaler Which databases does it not work in? What if I remove the PostgreSQL requirement and replace it with, say, h2?

Comment: I looked into this a bit. Oracle behaves like PostgreSQL in this respect (throws ORA-08177). The SQL standard has nothing to say about the topic, which is somewhat in line with its confusing and contradictory definition of isolation levels. This might be a good topic for a new question!

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I've never been able to use option 2 in Oracle or DB2. Maybe I coded it wrong. Maybe this a topic for a new question, since I would love to see a working solution.